# Is it true that a VPS's disk performance dont scale well (for Solr)?

Tags: solr, hosting, virtualhost, vps

I plan to run **Solr** cores for multiple clients. I thought Linode offers solid performance, stability and a scalable upgrade plan.

Solr is a high-performance full text search engine, written as a REST app in JSP. A source whom I look up to says that disk-intensive apps dont scale **as gracefully** as CPU-intensive tasks in a VPS environment. So, past a "point", if I am serving twice as many clients, I should order twice as many instances, rather than upgrading them. Or I need cloud services with load-balancing such as EC2, where multiple instances scale gracefully.

Is this true, especially for a modern host like Linode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Solr is a disk-IO-intensive application. We run [Websolr](http://websolr.com/) in Amazon EC2 and have spent a lot of time benchmarking and tuning both their instance stores and EBS RAID devices in order to get the best price to performance ratio that we can.

Really, the best answer for you here will be to benchmark your disk performance and compare a few different setups. Measure IO operations per second, read and write bandwidth, and create some timed Solr benchmarks as well. (Large reindexing task, large search volume, etc.) Compare those to some different setups and see which one gives you the most favorable price to performance ratio.